# How do you search for images or albums in Google+

Tags: google-plus-photos, picasa-web-albums

I believe that my images from Google+ and from Picasa web album can both be found in either application. I can search for an album name or an image caption or a file name in Picasa web album. Can I do the same from Google+?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can.

Answer (score 2):

The search in Google+ currently doesn't allow you to search through photo information. However, Google's Search Plus your World can provide the results you're looking for directly in Google's regular search. Here's some [documentation on personalized search results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2409866&topic=2413802&ctx=topic)

From the regular Google search box photos will surface in the results (in the Images section) if you are signed into Google. Caption information is also searchable.

Edit: Another help center article on [personal search results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1710607)